# solr delete by id using coldfusion cfhttp

Tags: solr, coldfusion, coldfusion-8, cfhttp

I want to delete docs by id via cfhttp.
But it doesn't function.
Can anyone help? What is wrong?

```
<cfhttp method="get" url="#elm_solr_url#update/?">
    <cfhttpparam name="stream.body" 
        type="FormField" 
        value="<delete><query>id:888_1100_1509_1_1</query></delete>">
    <cfhttpparam name="commit" type="FormField" value="true"> 
</cfhttp>
```

Comment: What happens, error message?

Comment: why aren't you using `<cfindex>` to do the same thing?  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/17456337/492335

Comment: I'm no expert on this tag, the combination of method="get" and type="formfield" looks fishy.

Comment: ... and you should probably be using `method="POST"`, and `type="XML"` and passing an actual XML object (use `<cfxml>` for instance) instead of a string that looks like XML

Comment: Thanks for reply. I can't use <cfindex because I use Coldfusion version 8.I get the error message: **org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Missing ContentType**

Comment: The error message cames if I use the code width variables below:  `<cfhttp method="get" url="http://localhost:8983/solr/update/?">
<cfhttpparam name="stream.body" type="FormField" value="%3Cdelete%3E%3Cquery%3Eid:#P_ID#_#M_ID#_#E_ID#_#E_Count#_2%3C/query%3E%3C/delete%3E">
<cfhttpparam name="commit" type="FormField" value="true"></cfhttp>`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
<cfxml variable="deleteID">
        <delete><id>888_1100_1509_1_1</id></delete>
</cfxml>

<cfhttp method="POST" url="#elm_solr_url#update/">
    <cfhttpparam type="XML" value="#deleteID#">
</cfhttp>
```

OR, something like:

```
<cfhttp method="GET" url="#elm_solr_url#update/">
    <cfhttpparam type="url" name="stream.body" value="#URLEncodedFormat('<delete><id>888_1100_1509_1_1</id></delete>')#">
</cfhttp>
```

You might want to read http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages

Comment: Me neither.  Error message?

Comment: Now, its work with this code: `<cfhttp method="post" url="http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/update/?">
<cfhttpparam type="FormField" name="stream.body" value="<delete><id>#P_ID#_#M_ID#_#E_ID#_#E_Count#_1</id></delete>">
<cfhttpparam type="FormField" name="commit" value="true">
</cfhttp>`

Comment: So in other words all you had to do was change your original code from method=get to method=post?